# Issue with Configurable Products Out of stock Products Price does not fluctuate in Magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, configurable-swatches, configurable-product-options

**we are facing issue in Magento 2.3.2 version:**

Here we are using default Magento 2 Mutli-inventory Management. In Configurable Products I made some changes to show Out of Stock Products to display this on frontEnd.

**But I am facing issue while select Out of Stock Product, Price does not Fluctuates** but when I select Instock products this fluctuates properly.

> Path: frontend\VendorName\ThemeName\Magento_ConfigurableProduct\web\js\configurable.js

```
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'mage/template',
  'mage/translate',
  'priceUtils',
  'priceBox',
  'jquery/ui',
  'jquery/jquery.parsequery'
], function ($, _, mageTemplate, $t, priceUtils) {
'use strict';

$.widget('mage.configurable', {
    options: {
        superSelector: '.super-attribute-select',
        selectSimpleProduct: '[name="selected_configurable_option"]',
        priceHolderSelector: '.price-box',
        spConfig: {},
        state: {},
        priceFormat: {},
        optionTemplate: '<%- data.label %>' +
        '<% if (typeof data.finalPrice.value !== "undefined") { %>' +
        ' <%- data.finalPrice.formatted %>' +
        '<% } %>',
        mediaGallerySelector: '[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]',
        mediaGalleryInitial: null,
        slyOldPriceSelector: '.sly-old-price',
        normalPriceLabelSelector: '.normal-price .price-label',

        /**
         * Defines the mechanism of how images of a gallery should be
         * updated when user switches between configurations of a product.
         *
         * As for now value of this option can be either 'replace' or 'prepend'.
         *
         * @type {String}
         */
        gallerySwitchStrategy: 'replace',
        tierPriceTemplateSelector: '#tier-prices-template',
        tierPriceBlockSelector: '[data-role="tier-price-block"]',
        tierPriceTemplate: ''
    },

    /**
     * Creates widget
     * @private
     */
    _create: function () {
        // Initial setting of various option values
        this._initializeOptions();

        // Override defaults with URL query parameters and/or inputs values
        this._overrideDefaults();

        // Change events to check select reloads
        this._setupChangeEvents();

        // Fill state
        this._fillState();

        // Setup child and prev/next settings
        this._setChildSettings();

        // Setup/configure values to inputs
        this._configureForValues();

        $(this.element).trigger('configurable.initialized');
    },

    /**
     * Initialize tax configuration, initial settings, and options values.
     * @private
     */
    _initializeOptions: function () {
        var options = this.options,
            gallery = $(options.mediaGallerySelector),
            priceBoxOptions = $(this.options.priceHolderSelector).priceBox('option').priceConfig || null;

        if (priceBoxOptions && priceBoxOptions.optionTemplate) {
            options.optionTemplate = priceBoxOptions.optionTemplate;
        }

        if (priceBoxOptions && priceBoxOptions.priceFormat) {
            options.priceFormat = priceBoxOptions.priceFormat;
        }
        options.optionTemplate = mageTemplate(options.optionTemplate);
        options.tierPriceTemplate = $(this.options.tierPriceTemplateSelector).html();

        options.settings = options.spConfig.containerId ?
            $(options.spConfig.containerId).find(options.superSelector) :
            $(options.superSelector);

        options.values = options.spConfig.defaultValues || {};
        options.parentImage = $('[data-role=base-image-container] img').attr('src');

        this.inputSimpleProduct = this.element.find(options.selectSimpleProduct);

        gallery.data('gallery') ?
            this._onGalleryLoaded(gallery) :
            gallery.on('gallery:loaded', this._onGalleryLoaded.bind(this, gallery));

    },

    /**
     * Override default options values settings with either URL query parameters or
     * initialized inputs values.
     * @private
     */
    _overrideDefaults: function () {
        var hashIndex = window.location.href.indexOf('#');

        if (hashIndex !== -1) {
            this._parseQueryParams(window.location.href.substr(hashIndex + 1));
        }

        if (this.options.spConfig.inputsInitialized) {
            this._setValuesByAttribute();
        }
    },

    /**
     * Parse query parameters from a query string and set options values based on the
     * key value pairs of the parameters.
     * @param {*} queryString - URL query string containing query parameters.
     * @private
     */
    _parseQueryParams: function (queryString) {
        var queryParams = $.parseQuery({
            query: queryString
        });

        $.each(queryParams, $.proxy(function (key, value) {
            this.options.values[key] = value;
        }, this));
    },

    /**
     * Override default options values with values based on each element's attribute
     * identifier.
     * @private
     */
    _setValuesByAttribute: function () {
        this.options.values = {};
        $.each(this.options.settings, $.proxy(function (index, element) {
            var attributeId;

            if (element.value) {
                attributeId = element.id.replace(/[a-z]*/, '');
                this.options.values[attributeId] = element.value;
            }
        }, this));
    },

    /**
     * Set up .on('change') events for each option element to configure the option.
     * @private
     */
    _setupChangeEvents: function () {
        $.each(this.options.settings, $.proxy(function (index, element) {
            $(element).on('change', this, this._configure);
        }, this));
    },

    /**
     * Iterate through the option settings and set each option's element configuration,
     * attribute identifier. Set the state based on the attribute identifier.
     * @private
     */
    _fillState: function () {
        $.each(this.options.settings, $.proxy(function (index, element) {
            var attributeId = element.id.replace(/[a-z]*/, '');

            if (attributeId && this.options.spConfig.attributes[attributeId]) {
                element.config = this.options.spConfig.attributes[attributeId];
                element.attributeId = attributeId;
                this.options.state[attributeId] = false;
            }
        }, this));
    },

    /**
     * Set each option's child settings, and next/prev option setting. Fill (initialize)
     * an option's list of selections as needed or disable an option's setting.
     * @private
     */
    _setChildSettings: function () {
        var childSettings = [],
            settings = this.options.settings,
            index = settings.length,
            option;

        while (index--) {
            option = settings[index];

            if (index) {
                option.disabled = true;
            } else {
                this._fillSelect(option);
            }

            _.extend(option, {
                childSettings: childSettings.slice(),
                prevSetting: settings[index - 1],
                nextSetting: settings[index + 1]
            });

            childSettings.push(option);
        }
    },



    /**
     * Setup for all configurable option settings. Set the value of the option and configure
     * the option, which sets its state, and initializes the option's choices, etc.
     * @private
     */
    _configureForValues: function () {
        if (this.options.values) {
            this.options.settings.each($.proxy(function (index, element) {
                var attributeId = element.attributeId;

                element.value = this.options.values[attributeId] || '';
                this._configureElement(element);
            }, this));
        }
    },

    /**
     * Event handler for configuring an option.
     * @private
     * @param {Object} event - Event triggered to configure an option.
     */
    _configure: function (event) {
        event.data._configureElement(this);
    },

    /**
     * Configure an option, initializing it's state and enabling related options, which
     * populates the related option's selection and resets child option selections.
     * @private
     * @param {*} element - The element associated with a configurable option.
     */
    _configureElement: function (element) {
        this.simpleProduct = this._getSimpleProductId(element);

        if (element.value) {
            this.options.state[element.config.id] = element.value;

            if (element.nextSetting) {
                element.nextSetting.disabled = false;
                this._fillSelect(element.nextSetting);
                this._resetChildren(element.nextSetting);
            } else {
                if (!!document.documentMode) { //eslint-disable-line
                    this.inputSimpleProduct.val(element.options[element.selectedIndex].config.allowedProducts[0]);
                } else {
                    this.inputSimpleProduct.val(element.selectedOptions[0].config.allowedProducts[0]);
                }
            }
        } else {
            this._resetChildren(element);
        }

        this._reloadPrice();
        this._displayRegularPriceBlock(this.simpleProduct);
        this._displayTierPriceBlock(this.simpleProduct);
        this._displayNormalPriceLabel();
        this._changeProductImage();
    },

    /**
     * Change displayed product image according to chosen options of configurable product
     *
     * @private
     */
    _changeProductImage: function () {
        var images,
            initialImages = this.options.mediaGalleryInitial,
            galleryObject = $(this.options.mediaGallerySelector).data('gallery');

        if (!galleryObject) {
            return;
        }

        images = this.options.spConfig.images[this.simpleProduct];

        if (images) {
            if (this.options.gallerySwitchStrategy === 'prepend') {
                images = images.concat(initialImages);
            }

            images = $.extend(true, [], images);
            images = this._setImageIndex(images);

            galleryObject.updateData(images);

            $(this.options.mediaGallerySelector).AddFotoramaVideoEvents({
                selectedOption: this.simpleProduct,
                dataMergeStrategy: this.options.gallerySwitchStrategy
            });
        } else {
            galleryObject.updateData(initialImages);
            $(this.options.mediaGallerySelector).AddFotoramaVideoEvents();
        }

        galleryObject.first();
    },

    /**
     * Set correct indexes for image set.
     *
     * @param {Array} images
     * @private
     */
    _setImageIndex: function (images) {
        var length = images.length,
            i;

        for (i = 0; length > i; i++) {
            images[i].i = i + 1;
        }

        return images;
    },

    /**
     * For a given option element, reset all of its selectable options. Clear any selected
     * index, disable the option choice, and reset the option's state if necessary.
     * @private
     * @param {*} element - The element associated with a configurable option.
     */
    _resetChildren: function (element) {
        if (element.childSettings) {
            _.each(element.childSettings, function (set) {
                set.selectedIndex = 0;
                set.disabled = true;
            });

            if (element.config) {
                this.options.state[element.config.id] = false;
            }
        }
    },

    /**
     * Populates an option's selectable choices.
     * @private
     * @param {*} element - Element associated with a configurable option.
     */
    _fillSelect: function (element) {
        var attributeId = element.id.replace(/[a-z]*/, ''),
            options = this._getAttributeOptions(attributeId),
            prevConfig,
            index = 1,
            allowedProducts,
            i,
            j;

        this._clearSelect(element);
        element.options[0] = new Option('', '');
        element.options[0].innerHTML = this.options.spConfig.chooseText;
        prevConfig = false;

        if (element.prevSetting) {
            prevConfig = element.prevSetting.options[element.prevSetting.selectedIndex];
        }


        if (options) {

            for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                allowedProducts = [];

                /* eslint-disable max-depth */
                if (prevConfig) {
                    for (j = 0; j < options[i].products.length; j++) {
                        // prevConfig.config can be undefined
                        if (prevConfig.config &&
                            prevConfig.config.allowedProducts &&
                            prevConfig.config.allowedProducts.indexOf(options[i].products[j]) > -1) {
                            allowedProducts.push(options[i].products[j]);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    allowedProducts = options[i].products.slice(0);
                }

                if (allowedProducts.length > 0){
                    options[i].allowedProducts = allowedProducts;
                    element.options[index] = new Option(this._getOptionLabel(options[i]), options[i].id);

                    if (typeof options[i].price !== 'undefined') {
                        element.options[index].setAttribute('price', options[i].prices);
                    }

                    element.options[index].config = options[i];
                    index++;
                }else{
                    options[i].allowedProducts = allowedProducts;
                    element.options[index] = new Option(this._getOptionLabel(options[i]), options[i].id);

                    if (typeof options[i].price !== 'undefined') {
                        element.options[index].setAttribute('price', options[i].prices);
                    }

                    //Oscp Start of Code For Show Product

                     var stockflag = 0;
                     for (var ps = 0; ps < options[i].allowedProducts.length; ps++) {
                     if(this.options.spConfig.index[options[i].allowedProducts[ps]]['current-stock']) {
                     stockflag++;
                     }
                     }
                     if(!stockflag) {
                     // element.options[index].setAttribute('disabled','disabled' );
                     element.options[index].innerHTML = this._getOptionLabel(options[i])+' - '+$t('Out of Stock');
                     }


                    //Oscp End of Code For Show Product

                    element.options[index].config = options[i];
                    index++;
                }

                /* eslint-enable max-depth */
            }
        }
    },

    /**
     * Generate the label associated with a configurable option. This includes the option's
     * label or value and the option's price.
     * @private
     * @param {*} option - A single choice among a group of choices for a configurable option.
     * @return {String} The option label with option value and price (e.g. Black +1.99)
     */
    _getOptionLabel: function (option) {
        return option.label;
    },

    /**
     * Removes an option's selections.
     * @private
     * @param {*} element - The element associated with a configurable option.
     */
    _clearSelect: function (element) {
        var i;

        for (i = element.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            element.remove(i);
        }
    },

    /**
     * Retrieve the attribute options associated with a specific attribute Id.
     * @private
     * @param {Number} attributeId - The id of the attribute whose configurable options are sought.
     * @return {Object} Object containing the attribute options.
     */
    _getAttributeOptions: function (attributeId) {
        if (this.options.spConfig.attributes[attributeId]) {
            return this.options.spConfig.attributes[attributeId].options;
        }
    },

    /**
     * Reload the price of the configurable product incorporating the prices of all of the
     * configurable product's option selections.
     */
    _reloadPrice: function () {
        $(this.options.priceHolderSelector).trigger('updatePrice', this._getPrices());
    },

    /**
     * Get product various prices
     * @returns {{}}
     * @private
     */
    _getPrices: function () {
        var prices = {},
            elements = _.toArray(this.options.settings),
            hasProductPrice = false;

        _.each(elements, function (element) {
            var selected = element.options[element.selectedIndex],
                config = selected && selected.config,
                priceValue = {};

            if (config && config.allowedProducts.length === 1 && !hasProductPrice) {
                priceValue = this._calculatePrice(config);
                hasProductPrice = true;
            }

            prices[element.attributeId] = priceValue;
        }, this);

        return prices;
    },

    /**
     * Returns prices for configured products
     *
     * @param {*} config - Products configuration
     * @returns {*}
     * @private
     */
    _calculatePrice: function (config) {
        var displayPrices = $(this.options.priceHolderSelector).priceBox('option').prices,
            newPrices = this.options.spConfig.optionPrices[_.first(config.allowedProducts)];

        _.each(displayPrices, function (price, code) {
            if (newPrices[code]) {
                displayPrices[code].amount = newPrices[code].amount - displayPrices[code].amount;
            }
        });

        return displayPrices;
    },

    /**
     * Returns Simple product Id
     *  depending on current selected option.
     *
     * @private
     * @param {HTMLElement} element
     * @returns {String|undefined}
     */
    _getSimpleProductId: function (element) {
        // TODO: Rewrite algorithm. It should return ID of
        //        simple product based on selected options.
        var allOptions = element.config.options,
            value = element.value,
            config;

        config = _.filter(allOptions, function (option) {
            return option.id === value;
        });
        config = _.first(config);

        return _.isEmpty(config) ?
            undefined :
            _.first(config.allowedProducts);

    },

    /**
     * Show or hide regular price block
     *
     * @param {*} optionId
     * @private
     */
    _displayRegularPriceBlock: function (optionId) {
        var shouldBeShown = true;

        _.each(this.options.settings, function (element) {
            if (element.value === '') {
                shouldBeShown = false;
            }
        });

        if ( typeof optionId == 'undefined' || shouldBeShown && (this.options.spConfig.optionPrices[optionId].oldPrice.amount !== this.options.spConfig.optionPrices[optionId].finalPrice.amount)) {
            $(this.options.slyOldPriceSelector).show();
        } else {
            $(this.options.slyOldPriceSelector).hide();
        }
    },

    /**
     * Show or hide normal price label
     *
     * @private
     */
    _displayNormalPriceLabel: function () {
        var shouldBeShown = false;

        _.each(this.options.settings, function (element) {
            if (element.value === '') {
                shouldBeShown = true;
            }
        });

        if (shouldBeShown) {
            $(this.options.normalPriceLabelSelector).show();
        } else {
            $(this.options.normalPriceLabelSelector).hide();
        }
    },

    /**
     * Callback which fired after gallery gets initialized.
     *
     * @param {HTMLElement} element - DOM element associated with gallery.
     */
    _onGalleryLoaded: function (element) {
        var galleryObject = element.data('gallery');

        this.options.mediaGalleryInitial = galleryObject.returnCurrentImages();
    },

    /**
     * Show or hide tier price block
     *
     * @param {*} optionId
     * @private
     */
    _displayTierPriceBlock: function (optionId) {
        var options, tierPriceHtml;

        if (typeof optionId != 'undefined' &&
            this.options.spConfig.optionPrices[optionId].tierPrices != [] // eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
        ) {
            options = this.options.spConfig.optionPrices[optionId];

            if (this.options.tierPriceTemplate) {
                tierPriceHtml = mageTemplate(this.options.tierPriceTemplate, {
                    'tierPrices': options.tierPrices,
                    '$t': $t,
                    'currencyFormat': this.options.spConfig.currencyFormat,
                    'priceUtils': priceUtils
                });
                $(this.options.tierPriceBlockSelector).html(tierPriceHtml).show();
            }
        } else {
            $(this.options.tierPriceBlockSelector).hide();
        }
    }
});

return $.mage.configurable;
});
```

Any help will appreciate.